# Is there a performance/responsivness gain when running Azure-CLI in WSL?

Tags: azure, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-cli

There are three scenarios of running `Azure-CLI` on Windows 10:

1. Installing `Azure CLI` package for Windows and run in cmd/pwsh
2. Installing `Azure CLI` package for Windows and run inside WSL
3. Installing via `curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash` in WSL and only run from there

Is there any benefit in choosing one scenario over another? As `Azure-CLI` is very slow on Windows I would love to see some performance improvement.

Comment: Is there anything unexpected in the answer? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Azure CLI, I would more recommend the Linux environment, it means the WSL. According to my experience, almost the Azure CLI documents show the example is in the Linux, and there is something different between Linux and Windows, so if you want to use the Azure CLI command in windows, sometimes, you need to change the example command to adapt the Windows environment. For example, when you use the Windows cmd, it's impossible to make it work:

```
var=$(az account show --query id)
```

But it's usable in Linux. So I recommend the WSL.